# Why does MATLAB image processing Toolbox doesn't use equal bin size in imhist?

Tags: matlab, histogram

According to MATLAB's documentation the $p$-th bin contains the pixels between
$A\frac{(p-1.5)}{n-1}\leq x<A\frac{p-0.5}{n-1}$, where $x$ is the pixel intensity, and $n$ is the number of bins.

As far as I can understand this, $A$ is a scaling factor that is the maximal value of the data type used (e.g. if $A=1$ we consider an image with $x\in[0,1]$).

What I don't really understand, why we use the constants in the expression; for the first bin (assuming that MATLAB considers $p=1$ instead of $p=0$ as the first bin) we put values between $x\in[\frac{-0.5}{(n-1)}, \frac{0.5}{(n-1)}]$, but we have values between $x\in[0,1]$ so the effective width of the bin is only half of the "normal" bins (same goes to the last bin). Why don't MATLAB use $A\frac{p}{n-1}\leq x<A\frac{p+1}{n-1}$ for $p\in[0,n-1]$?

Comment: Should be moved to StackOverflow, it is Matlab specific question.

Comment: I'm not sure, because I though that it has a practical DSP-related reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was actually pretty easy and not MATLAB-related: if you divide your domain equidistantly (and choose these values as the **representative value** of the corresponding quantization level) and pick thresholds at the centroid of each of these intervals endpoints you get the thresholds that MATLAB uses.